# How to determine "native" sizes for bitmapped fonts?

Tags: fonts

I have installed Emacs24 (`emacs24-lucid` from `wheezy-backports`) on an otherwise `stable` Debian system, and I run it under X11

Under X11, Emacs24 displays some font families, such as ProFontIIx, as non-antialiased fonts only when I choose the size of one of the bitmapped fonts available for the family.  The problem is to figure out what those "magic" sizes are.

I tried `xfontsel`, but for some reason `ProFontIIx` is not among the options it gives (even though this font is installed, and is found by Emacs24).

How else can I figure out the sizes that will produce non-antialiased fonts?

(Just to be clear: I do *not* want anti-aliasing.)

Comment: Are you sure this font is a bitmap font?

Comment: @didierc: my understanding is that the collection includes several bitmapped sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's using *[fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html)* as the simple name suggests (i.e. not an X11 font name with 14 dashes), then you need to use `fc-list` to list the fonts found in the directories that fontconfig searchs (configured via `fonts.conf` files, not the X11 font path that `xlsfonts` uses).

For instance, a partial listing of the various sizes of the Courier font installed on my system, with `pixelsize` shown for the bitmap fonts and omitted for the scalable fonts.

```
% fc-list Courier : family style pixelsize
Courier:style=Bold Italic
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=34
Courier:style=Regular
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=12
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=14
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=8
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=11
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=10
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=20
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=17
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=18
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=25
Courier:style=Regular:pixelsize=24
...
```